# How to check whether a value exists in an associative array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have an array that is the result of a SELECT query and would like to check whether a certain value exists in that array.
I tried the following but this does not find the value and always returns that the value does not exist in the array.

I am assuming I am referring wrongly to the array. Can someone show me how to do this right?

**My array:**

```
array ( 0 => array ( 'itemName' => 'bandwidth', 'itemType' => 'number', 'itemUnit' => 'mbit', ), 1 => array ( 'itemName' => 'bSize', 'itemType' => 'number', 'itemUnit' => 'sqm', ), 2 => array ( 'itemName' => 'bArea', 'itemType' => 'number', 'itemUnit' => 'sqm', ), )
```

**My PHP:**

```
// ...
$resultC = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
var_export($resultC);
if(in_array('bandwidth', $resultC)) {
    echo 'exists in array';
} else {
    echo 'does not exist in array';
}
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table  WHERE %your_condition%`

Comment: @u_mulder: Thank you. This is not what I am looking for here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the combination of `array_column` with `in_array` for your case.

```
$resultC = [
    0 => ['itemName' => 'bandwidth', 'itemType' => 'number', 'itemUnit' => 'mbit'],
    1 => ['itemName' => 'bSize', 'itemType' => 'number', 'itemUnit' => 'sqm'],
    2 => ['itemName' => 'bArea', 'itemType' => 'number', 'itemUnit' => 'sqm'],
];

return in_array('bandwidth', array_column($resultC, 'itemName'));
```